# Clojure: Difference between a list and a function that returns a list

Tags: clojure

I'm a Clojure newbie. I'm trying to understand why the second form doesn't work:

First form:

```
user=>(def nums(range 3))
(0 1 2)
user=>(map #(list %1) nums)
((0) (1) (2))
```

Second form:

```
user=> (map #(list %1) (0 1 2))
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn 
(NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is the expression `(0 1 2)`, which is interpreted as `0` applied to `1` and `2`; that's impossible because `0` isn't a function.

```
(map #(list %1) '(0 1 2))
```

works as intended, though.

Answer (score 5):

Because `(0 1 2)` means call function 0 with args 1 and 2, but 0 is not a function. So you need to make is a list rather than function application using quote or list function i.e `'(0 1 2)`
OR `(list 0 1 2)`

Comment: Yes, I've realized after submitting the question, but couldn answer myself because of StackOverflow restrictions. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, you _can_ answer your own questions on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Maybe his rank was too low or something?

Answer (score 4):

larsmans and Ankur have it.  I realize this is a trivial example, but it would probably be more idiomatic to use a vector rather than a list:

```
(map #(list %1) [0 1 2])
```

You can also use `%` instead of `%1` when there's only one arg passed to the anonymous function.

```
(map #(list %) [0 1 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
user=> (map list (range 3))
((0) (1) (2))
user=> (map list '(0 1 2))
((0) (1) (2))
user=> (map list [0 1 2])
((0) (1) (2))
```